How do you document this.field in the Mocha TestContext with JSDoc types in a before() hook so that other it() tests and IntelliJ know what it is?
I want IntelliJ (or any similar IDE, like WebStorm or VSCode) to give me auto-complete for my fields that I define in my test context in a Mocha.js before() hook. I then want to be able to see the auto-complete documentation of that field in all of my unit tests that use that test context.
Here is an example:
describe('Awesome Test Code', async function()
{

  /** A super expensive thing that each unit test needs. **/
  class ExpensiveThing { expensive = true; }

  /**
   * Run this once before the first test in this describe block.
   * {@link https://mochajs.org/#hooks Mocha Hooks}
   * {@link https://mochajs.org/#global-teardown-fixtures Mocha Test Contexts}
   */
  before('the first test', async function()
  {
    // We can prepare anything we want here and set it on this
    // so that each unit test can access it when the unit test runs.
    // This is better than initializing it in the describe() block
    // because then the code would run when mocha parses the tests
    // and it would get executed even if the test is not run.
    // https://mochajs.org/#global-teardown-fixtures
    
    this.expensiveThingUsedForTheTests = new ExpensiveThing();
    //      ⬆️                                 ⬆️
    // ________|__________________________________|________
    // !!! I want to define the type of this field here !!!
    // ----------------------------------------------------
  });

  it('should be easy', async function(){

    this.expensiveThingUsedForTheTests.expensive = false;
    //      ⬆️                          ⬆️
    // ________|___________________________|_________________________
    // !!! I want this to give me auto-complete and documentation !!!
    // --------------------------------------------------------------

    assert.equal(this.expensiveThingUsedForTheTests.expensive, false, 'This was not easy!');
  });

});

This is what I see instead, when I push CTRL+Q on the field in IntelliJ IDEA:


The trick is to use the @typedef JSDoc tag along with the @this tag on each method that has that test context. You can use the @type tag to document the this.x field in the before() hook.
The documentation is here:
JSDoc @typedef - To define a name for the test context.
JSDoc @this - To link this to the test contexts up.
JSDoc @type - To document the field on this.x.
This is what I mean:
    // Add the @this JSDoc comment to specify what the test context is that we are defining in the before() hook:
    /**
     * @this ThisTestContext
     */
    before('the first test', async function()
    {
        // Create a definition for our specific test context.
        // You can use any name instead of 'ThisTestContext'.
        // https://jsdoc.app/tags-typedef

        /**
         * The context for the awesome unit tests. Use this.x to set the test context.
         * <p>
         * {@link https://jsdoc.app/tags-typedef JSDoc @typedef}
         * {@link https://jsdoc.app/tags-this JSDoc @this}
         * {@link https://jsdoc.app/tags-type JSDoc @type}
         * {@link https://mochajs.org/#hooks Mocha Hooks}
         * {@link https://mochajs.org/#global-teardown-fixtures Mocha Test Contexts}
         * @typedef {object} ThisTestContext
         */


        // Add the @type JSDoc comment above the field you want to document:

        /** {@type ExpensiveThing} The expensive thing that we create once and reuse across tests. **/
        this.expensiveThingUsedForTheTests = new ExpensiveThing();
        //      ⬆️                                 ⬆️
        // ________|__________________________________|___________________________
        // !!! You just define this normally, plus a @type JSDoc comment above !!!
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    });

    // Add the @this JSDoc comment to link this to the same test context defined in the before() hook:
    /**
     * @this ThisTestContext
     */
    it('should be easy', async function(){

        this.expensiveThingUsedForTheTests.expensive = false;
        //      ⬆️                          ⬆️
        // ________|___________________________|____________________
        // !!! Now all the auto-complete and documentation works !!!
        // ---------------------------------------------------------

        assert.equal(this.expensiveThingUsedForTheTests.expensive, false, 'This was much easier!');
    });

Now we can see the auto-complete working in IntelliJ:

